# Can the mutual information of a "cell" be negative?

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory

Please forgive me if this is not the right Stack Exchange (I also posted it at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5698/can-the-mutual-information-of-a-cell-be-negative)).  Please also forgive me for inventing terms.

For discrete random variables X and Y, the mutual information of X and Y can be defined as follows:
$I(X;Y) = \sum_{y \in Y} \sum_{x \in X} 
                 p(x,y) \log{ \left( \frac{p(x,y)}{p_1(x)\,p_2(y)}
                              \right) }, \,\!$

I will define the mutual information of a "cell" $x_0$ to be:
$CI(x_0,Y) = \sum_{y \in Y} p(x_0,y) \log{ \left( \frac{p(x_0,y)}{p_1(x_0)\,p_2(y)}
                              \right) }, \,\!$

I'm not sure if this quantity goes by another name.  Essentially I'm restricting focus to a single state of variable X (and then the full MI can be calculated by summing all the cell MIs).

My question: is it guaranteed that $CI(x_0,Y) \ge 0$?  We know $I(X;Y)\ge0$ and we know that the pointwise mutual information can be negative.  I feel like CI should be nonnegative and that I might be missing some obvious proof.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By the simple transformation $p(x_0, y) = p(y | x_0)p(x_0) $ your expression merely becomes $p(x_0) KL(p (y|x_0), p(y))$, where $KL(p,q)$ is the Kullback-Leibler divergence, and is always positive. therefore, your expression is always positive.

Comment: Terrific, thanks!  I was fooling around with similar transformations but somehow missed the obvious.

Comment: yes. this particular transformation turns out to be very handy.